# MongoDB C# - Implementing IBsonArraySerializer

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following object:

```
class MyObject
{
    ...
    Dictionary<string, object> Properties
}
```

and I would like to be able to do CRUD operations with the Properties without having to get the whole object, update the dictionary and update the object.

First, I'd like to know if this is even possible? if not, this question has no point :)

I implemented code like this:

```
var KVP = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Name, Value);
var AddUpdate = Builders<MyObject>.Update.Push(_ => _.Properties, KVP);
```

to add an entry, and was planning to use:

```
Projection.ElemMatch(_ => _.Properties, __ => __.Key == Name)
```

to retrieve the data.

But I get this:

> The serializer for field 'Properties' must implement
>   IBsonArraySerializer and provide item serialization info.

I was wondering if I can implement the serializer just for the *Properties* field, or if I have to do it for the whole class?

Someone looked into this here: [mongo-db-and-c-dictionary-serialisation-part-1-the-problem](http://www.danharman.net/2011/09/14/mongodb-and-c-dictionary-serialisation-part-1-the-problem/), but he didn't write 'part 2' with the full solution :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb: implement IBsonArraySerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740726/mongodb-implement-ibsonarrayserializer)

Comment: @Liam, I'm not sure, that was from 4 years ago :)